# How do I find a replacement for this SMD voltage regulator (top marking "ODM")?

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification, surface-mount

The 5 pin SMD voltage regulator:

[image: the 5 pin smd voltage regulator]

I need to replace this component because it is shorted (I think because it is extremely hot.) I am having trouble identifying which one to buy online because there seems to be a lot of them with varying ratings. I have tried searching the for 'ODM' name but it doesn't have any meaning. I just need a replacement that has the same rating.

The voltage on leg 1 = 1.6V, leg 2 = 0V, leg 3 = 3V, leg 4 = 0V, leg 5 = 3V

Comment: Your pin 3 is actually device pin 1

Comment: I dont really know much about electronics, just wanted to show which pin is which.

Comment: Did you remove this part and verify that *it* is shorted and not something else?

Comment: I would if i know how to test it. Do you have any suggestions how to test it? Also, is removing it from the board the only accurate way to verify it if its shorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the part you're asking about may be a [TLV700 200mA LDO Regulator](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv700.pdf?ts=1628097519313&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) the pins matchup with the drawings and the ODM top marking shows on a couple of variants:

[image: Surface marking]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Didnt expect to get an answer that quick.